# ScrollableResults.get() gives proxy instead of real entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I face problem during upgrade Hibernate-ORM from 4.3.11 to 5.2.18.

I execute query and I receive result as ScrollableResults object.
Previously in Hibernate 4 ScrollableResults.get() returned entity itself, but now in Hibernate 5 I received proxy. I checked and in both cases hibernate session has that entity as proxy.

That new situation causes problem, because in next step I want to clone that object using BeanUtils.cloneBean(). Now instead of new object I receive entity where all fields have null value.
I know I can unproxy User before clone process, but this is the least interesting solution for me.

My question is why ScrollableResults gives proxy now, and how can I enforce it to give me entity.
Maybe someone from Hibernate Team can explain me what has changed?

Greetings!